# How to create a new column based on whether the value in another column contains values of a list?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, conditional-statements

I want to create a new column based on whether the value in another column contains values of a list.

For example:
Below is the original dataframe

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| apple2876 | red |
| 3pear6 | red |
| 12banana28 | red |
| 1ab33pie2 | red |
| 2rbbwater | red |

I have a list `[apple, banana, water]`.

I want to create a new column based on whether column a contains certain text in this list. The new dataframe looks like this:

| a | b | c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| apple2876 | red | 1 |
| 3pear6 | red | 0 |
| 12banana28 | red | 1 |
| 1ab33pie2 | red | 0 |
| 2rbbwater | red | 1 |

Answer (score 4):

Let's try

```py
lst = ['apple', 'banana', 'water']
df['c'] = df['a'].str.contains('|'.join(lst)).astype(int)
```

```
print(df)

            a    b  c
0   apple2876  red  1
1      3pear6  red  0
2  12banana28  red  1
3   1ab33pie2  red  0
4   2rbbwater  red  1
```